# Font tag inside string tag is not read with Data Binding Android

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding

String resource:

```
<string name="hint_dob_mandatory">Date of birth<font color='#FFFF0000'>  *</font></string>
                  <!-- Already tried with '#FFFF0000', "#FFFF0000" -->
<string name="hint_dob">Date of birth</string>
```

Below piece of code is working fine:

```
android:hint="@string/hint_dob_mandatory"
```

Below is the actual output which is correctly fine: **(with normal use of string res)**

[image: output without use of data binding]

Here, issue with data binding:

```
 android:hint="@{ANY_TRUE_CONDITION ? @string/hint_dob_mandatory : @string/hint_dob}
```

Below is the actual output which is having issue: **(with using data binding of string res)**

[image: output with use of data binding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to look at the signature of the methods.
If you are NOT using databinding, you are actually using this method:

```
fun EditText.setHint(resourceId: Int)
```

When using Databinding, `@string/hint_dob_mandatory` will be resolved to a String automatically, and, in fact, your are using this method:

```
fun EditText.setHint(hint: CharSequence)
```

This first one handles the font tag nicely, but the second will just ignore it. Basically, Databinding is trying to be smart but by doing so, uses the wrong method.

Now, to solve it you have 2 options:

**1) Explicitly set a ResourceId for the hint**

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="hintResource"
        type="Integer" />
</data>

<EditText
    android:hint="@{hintResource}" />
```

With this approach, you need to set hintResource on your binding

```
binding.hintResource = R.string.hint
```

This effectively ensures, that the `setHint(res: Int)` variant is being used

**2) Import your R file**

```
<data>
    <import type="com.your.package.R" />
</data>

<EditText
    app:resourceHint="@{ANY_TRUE_CONDITION ? R.string.hint_dob_mandatory : R.string.hint_dob}
```

By importing the `R` file, you can use it in the dataBinding expression. By using R.string.hint you indicate that you use a Resource. Whereas @string/hint will actually convert that resource into a String.

Finally, a combination of the two are also possible, as well as creating a custom BindingAdapter. But in the end it's all the same, as long as you make sure to use an `@StringRes Int` instead of a `String`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I am using 2nd one from the above options.